# Implementing layered architecture in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, software-design, code-structure

For my software design class we were tasked to make a piece of software that would be designed using Domain driven design. My team and I chose to make a web app where coaches can input statistical data about their teams. Following the layered architecture described in DDD, what would be the correct way to structure my code?

The way we are implementing this is by using a DAO to make queries to our database then the results of these queries are passed to a Handler that creates a domain entity to later be passed to the user interface. The problem is that for each entity we would have to create a class for the entity, a Handler and a DAO for said entity.

Is there a better way?

Comment: There's really not enough information about the domain here to get any help. What statistical data you will capture. How will such data be collected? Try to explain the business use cases (the commands) and the rules that must be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Layered architecture is not specific to DDD.
DDD Domain Driven Design suggests that you design your system around your business.
What entities, what relationships, what transactional/change boundaries, denormalisation vs. duplication, etc.
Layered architecture, MVC, etc. are just an implementation detail. This doesn't mean that you shouldn't pay attention to them, but it's another point of view on your product which should be distinguished from the Domain view